# Match all in between two exclamations in PHP

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

So, I don't know anything about preg in php and though I tried getting into it, still my mind can't property get a good grasp of it's concept.

I am struggling to get everything in in between two exclamation points like this !!FIRSTNAME!!.

This is what i've done so far but is showing the ! in the result

```
preg_match('~[!!](.+?)[!!]~',$html, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the character class:

```
preg_match('~!!(.+?)!!~',$html, $matches);
```

The string you search for is in `$matches[1]`